# jsf a4j not working on popup screen

Tags: java, jsf

I am working in JSF

When I open popup screen my a4j ajax call doesn't work.

Where as same screen works if I don't do popup.

Is this usual thing?

---

Popup one page where ... few code like this..

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"%>
<%@ taglib uri="https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/ajax" prefix="a4j"%>
```

Delay set to

```
<a4j:queue requestDelay="500" ignoreDupResponses="true" />
```

and actual ajax call like

```
<a4j:commandLink 
    actionListener="#{insuranceBackingBean.viewAll}"
    ajaxSingle="true"
    reRender="formularyList, noRecFoundGridForFormulary, patientCurrentDemographicDetails,patientInsuranceDemographicDetails,conflictSection"
    eventsQueue="onClick"
    onclick="setEligibilityValues('#{insuranceBean.fromEligibility}','#{insuranceBean.payerMessage}','#{insuranceBean.pharmacyBenefitRetailCoverageStatus}','#{insuranceBean.pharmacyBenefitMailOrderCoverageStatus}','#{insuranceBean.pharmacyBenefitLTCCoverageStatus}','#{insuranceBean.pharmacyBenefitSpecialtyCoverageStatus}');setVisibleConflictGrid();"
    >
    <f:verbatim>View</f:verbatim>
    <f:param name="insuranceID" value="#{insuranceBean.id}" />
```

where `setEligibilityValues` is script which is being called but `insuranceBackingBean.viewAll` is not being called.

Is there any way to `troubleshoot` this???

Comment: More info please...it should work normally but there must be something in the way...hmmmmm mmmm

Comment: Thanks guys for your reply. I have updated the code. I need to hide this once you give the answer and help me ... :)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know which component/tag you use as popup, but i faced this problem many times with different components and the only solution i know is this: you should open the popup as a **modal** dialog. which means it should be rendered inside an **iframe**.

usually, if popup is not configured as modal, than it is usually rendered in a div/span and for some reason, ajax calls fail to execute on server side.